# How to update Machine Learning model deployed using Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory, azure-function-app, azure-functions-core-tools

I have a machine model that I deployed using docker on Azure Function(HTTP Trigger). Routinely, the directory of the machine learning model is expected to change and updated once a new file is uploaded to an Azure DataLake.

Please, How do I automate this process of updating the model on Azure Functions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since its a docker container, you would just want to build a new container with the new model and update the function app with the new image tag.

Azure Data Lake Storage supports Events that you can listen to, triggering the pipeline for the machine learning model, and then follow up with a CI/CD pipeline for building the docker image.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. How do I mount the new model thats stored in the Datalake in the Pipeline, so it can build the docker image again.